# Conditionally display pure HTML elements

Tags: html, jsf-2, conditional-statements

I would like to conditionally display the following elements:

```
<li>
  <h:link outcome="mypage" value="My Value" />
</li>
```

So my condition should determine if the `<li>` tag and all it's children would be displayed or not. AFAIK, I can't use `<f:verbatim>` because of the UIComponent inside the `<li>` tag (`<h:link>`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's another reason to not use `<f:verbatim>`: it's **deprecated** in JSF 2.0.

Use [`<ui:fragment>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/fragment.html). It's semantically more correct than a `<h:panelGroup>` (which by itself indeed renders nothing when no client side specific attributes are specified) and has also a bit less overhead.

```xml
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.show}">
    ...
</ui:fragment>
```

*(note: due to some bug, Netbeans seems to jerk that this attribute isn't supported, but this is untrue, it's definitely supported)*

Comment: right. the documentation doesn't say explicitly if `<h:panelGroup>` will render anything if no arguments were given. But we all know it, and you confirmed that. Also, I also don't like overloading responsibilities, since `<h:panelGroup>` is already used to render block or inline elements. So, `<ui:fragment>` is more properly for this kind of issue.

Comment: @BalusC sorry i don't want to pollute that answer with comments, but i didn't really understand the "renders nothing when no client side specific attributes are specified", i understand from your answer that its the main reason you choosed ui:fragment and not h:panelGroup but i don't understand what does that sentence mean. thanks for any explanation

Comment: @Tarik: try `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{true}">` and check HTML output. You'll see nothing, like `<ui:fragment rendered="#{true}">`. However once you add client side specific attributes to `<h:panelGroup>`, like `id`, `styleClass`, `title`, etc, then it'll render a HTML `<span>`.

Comment: @BalusC i tried <h:panelGroup rendered="#{true}">
<h:outputText value="panel"/>
</h:panelGroup> and <ui:fragment  rendered="#{true}">
<h:outputText value="fragment"/>
</ui:fragment> and the result seems to me normal, both display an outputText, what i am missing ?

Comment: @Tarik: Things change once you add client side attributes to `<h:panelGroup>`. It would then render a `<span>` which would end up in invalid HTML markup in OP's case (it doesn't belong around a `<li>`).

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the explanations, i can see the HTML output difference now! but i can't understand what kind of "invalid HTML markup" would happen, i tried the same case of the OP but i didn't have any invalid HTML.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the website :) i nested a `<p/>` inside the `h:panelGroup` and i saw now the HTML errors, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your elements inside a `h:panelGroup` and use your condition on the `rendered` attribute of the panelgroup.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="...">
  <li>
    <h:link outcome="mypage" value="My Value" />
  </li>
<h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: You are right, but `<ui:fragment>` is better since it's made for that. And it is more explicit (i.e. the user doesn't have to know that if there's not `style` or `styleClass`, nothing will be rendered)

Comment: I mean, nothing wrapping the elements

Comment: @bluefoot why would you need something to wrapp the elements ?