# Alternative to f:verbatim in JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, weblogic

Alternative to `f:verbatim` in JSF 2.1 for rendering purpose is needed. In my application I am using `ui:fragment` rendered instead of f:verbatim but it is not working in jsf 2.1.

Here i am providing my code

```
    <f:verbatim rendered="#{not empty focusField}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            // If the class is not set, do so now
            $("#menuContainer > ul:first:not(.sf-menu)").addClass("sf-menu");
            $("ul.sf-menu").supersubs({ 
                minWidth:    12,   // minimum width of sub-menus in em units 
                maxWidth:    27,   // maximum width of sub-menus in em units 
                extraWidth:  1     // extra width can ensure lines don't sometimes turn over 
                                   // due to slight rounding differences and font-family 
            }).superfish({
                delay:       300
            });   
        }); 
    </script>
    </f:verbatim>

<ui:component>
<ui:fragment  rendered="#{not empty focusField}">
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            // If the class is not set, do so now
            $("#menuContainer > ul:first:not(.sf-menu)").addClass("sf-menu");
            $("ul.sf-menu").supersubs({ 
                minWidth:    12,   // minimum width of sub-menus in em units 
                maxWidth:    27,   // maximum width of sub-menus in em units 
                extraWidth:  1     // extra width can ensure lines don't sometimes turn over 
                                   // due to slight rounding differences and font-family 
            }).superfish({
                delay:       300
            });   
        }); 
    </script>   </ui:fragment>
</ui:component>
```

I am getting this error

```
 Root cause of ServletException.
org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'demo' of flow 'demo' 
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:571)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:262)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3592)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2202)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1432)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

Caused By: javax.faces.FacesException: Component ID demo has already been found in the view.
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.render(FlowLifecycle.java:80)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:89)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)                                                                


Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID demo has already been found in the view.
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:910)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:894)
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what errors are you seeing? Seems like what you're doing should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238016/conditionally-display-pure-html-elements

Comment: whenever clicking CommandLike i am getting this error,it is regrading tag issue are any other,plz Help for this issue

Comment: It looks like a error i got from programmatically generated elements that you could get rid of by either using a transient view or by removing those ui elements from the view before rendering again.