# How can i make part of a value in a h:outputText Bold?

Tags: html, jsf

How can i make part of a value in a h:outputText Bold?
i want the Name in bold:

`<h:outputText value="Normal Text: #{Controller.Object.name}" />`

i tried: `<h:outputText value="Normal Text: <b>#{Controller.Object.name}</b>" />`

got this error: "*The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "h:outputText*" must not contain the '<' character."
after some searches here and others pages, found that the attribute `escape="false"` could fix this... but doesn't make difference for me,

`<h:outputText escape="false" value="Normal Text: <b>#{Controller.Object.name}</b>" />`

still got the same error.

has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Try to escape '<' character yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need `<h:outputText>`?

In Facelets you can just use EL in template text:

```html
Normal Text: <b>#{Controller.Object.name}</b>
```

If you really insist in using `<h:outputText>`, then you should indeed manually escape the XML entities and display it with `escape="false"`:

```
<h:outputText value="Normal Text: &lt;b&gt;#{Controller.Object.name}&lt;/b&gt;" escape="false" />
```

This not only reads uglier, but also puts a XSS attack hole open in case `#{Controller.Object.name}` is a client-controlled value.

#### See also:

- [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything)
- [CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf)

Comment: Thanks man! but i used `h:outputText ` because i need to set `rendered` attribute on few texts... i'm trying to do this with the first way... in last case i will use the last and vulnerable way

Comment: Just wrap in `<ui:fragment rendered="#{...}">`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238016/conditionally-display-pure-html-elements

Answer (score 0):

To me, it makes much more sense to put the `<p></p>` inside the text in the `.properties` file or wherever you are defining the `Controller.Object.name`value. Much cleaner and you don't have to mess with encoding symbols.