# Is there a do-while-loop construct in JSF or is it possible to run <ui:repeat> at least once, even if the bound list is empty?

Tags: jsf

Like, is it possible to run `<ui:repeat>` at least once, even if the bound collection is empty? Think:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{some.bean.some.collection}" var="item"  varStatus="status">  
   ... 
</ui:repeat>
```

How would I make it run at least once, regardless of what's in `some.bean.some.collection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such facility, at least not in the core JSF spec. You could write your own JSF component, of course, that is not terribly difficult.

That said, even if it were possible, I don't think this would be a great idea (that's probably why it's not included in core JSF).

With JSF, it's (IMHO) usually a good idea to keep the logic server-side, instead of putting it into the components and EL expressions. So I'd recommend to just let the getter in your bean return some placeholder element if the collection is empty. This gets trickier if the collection is also writable, but probably still doable.

It's perfectly acceptable to have your beans return data specifically tailored for one view of the data, and this is one example. See for example the concepts of *view model* and *presentation model* for more details.

---

Another approach:

Do you just want to show some placeholder text (or controls) if a list is empty? Such as "no data available", maybe with a button "Start import" or such.

Then you could put a second block of markup *after* the list, and wrap both in a container such as `ui:fragment` with `rendered` attribute, such that the list is rendered if there is data, and the placeholder block if not:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty some.bean.some.collection}">
    <ui:repeat value="#{some.bean.some.collection}" var="item" varStatus="status">  
       ... 
    </ui:repeat>  
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{empty some.bean.some.collection}">
<strong class="warning">No data available</strong>
</ui:fragment>
```

That way you can display an arbitrary replacement for the empty list.

Comment: +1. However, please use `ui:fragment` instead of `h:panelGroup` to solely render components. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6243585/2118909

Comment: @MathieuCastets: Thanks for the hint. Edited.